# Get row that matches all multiple rows from another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables:

1. One table contains `customer ids` and a `service id` that the `customer` subscribes to.
2. The second table contains the `service id's` and a `service description` for all types of `services`.

What I am trying to do is print out all the `customer ids` from the first table that have at least 5 matching unique services. Here is what I came up with but its super hacky:

```
select * from customers left join services where customer.serviceid = services.sid group by servicesid having count(servicesid) >= 5;
```

is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a properly formed database, then any value of `serviceid` should be valid.

If you want matching customers, use `group by`:

```
select c.customerid
from customers c
group by c.customerid
having count(servicesid) >= 5;
```

If there could be duplicates in the `customers` table, then use `count(distinct servicesid) >= 5`.